# pair values from different levels selecting one based on neighbor member

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to go through an array of objects w/ jq and convert that to csv. I can do the some of the selection and to csv part but what I'm struggling with is figuring out how to get the `Name` tag value of each object.

The json looks like this:

```
{
  "Groups": [],
  "Instances": [
    {
      "InstanceType": "m5.xlarge",
      "Tags": [
        {
          "Key": "jenkins_slave_type",
          "Value": "demand_ec2 small"
        },
        {
          "Key": "color",
          "Value": "jenkins"
        },
        {
          "Key": "role",
          "Value": "jenkins"
        },
        {
          "Key": "stack",
          "Value": "dev-us-east-1"
        },
        {
          "Key": "Name",
          "Value": "worker-jenkins"
        },
        {
          "Key": "secondary-role",
          "Value": "worker"
        }
      ],
      "VirtualizationType": "hvm",
      "CpuOptions": {
        "CoreCount": 2,
        "ThreadsPerCore": 2
      },
      "CapacityReservationSpecification": {
        "CapacityReservationPreference": "open"
      },
      "HibernationOptions": {
        "Configured": false
      },
      "MetadataOptions": {
        "State": "applied",
        "HttpTokens": "optional",
        "HttpPutResponseHopLimit": 1,
        "HttpEndpoint": "enabled"
      }
    }
  ]
} 
{
  "Groups": [],
  "Instances": [
    {
      "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
      "Tags": [
        {
          "Key": "Description",
          "Value": "test"
        },
        {
          "Key": "Name",
          "Value": "test-connection-cloud-sql"
        }
      ],
      "VirtualizationType": "hvm",
      "CpuOptions": {
        "CoreCount": 1,
        "ThreadsPerCore": 1
      },
      "CapacityReservationSpecification": {
        "CapacityReservationPreference": "open"
      },
      "HibernationOptions": {
        "Configured": false
      },
      "MetadataOptions": {
        "State": "applied",
        "HttpTokens": "optional",
        "HttpPutResponseHopLimit": 1,
        "HttpEndpoint": "enabled"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I can get to the instance type like this:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances | jq '.Reservations[] | {type: .Instances[].InstanceType}'
```

but I can't seem to get to the `Name` value in `Tags` thats not nested. I've done it this way but its still nested:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances | jq '.Reservations[] | {type: .Instances[].InstanceType, name: .Instances[].Tags[] | select (.Key == "Name")}'
```

Comment: What is the expected output of the above JSON?

Comment: ah, should be `{type: Instancetype, name: Name}`

Comment: Your question says converting to CSV

Comment: oh yeah...I can do the CSV part if I can get a flattened object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand `Instances` once to avoid a combinatorial explosion. To apply a filter to the result(s) of `select`, simply write the filter next to it.

```
.Reservations[].Instances[] | {InstanceType, name: .Tags[] | select(.Key == "Name") .Value}
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/pQn_IfWQ0X)</sup>